# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, ormlite-servicestack

I have an error on create or add product in mysql is there something wrong.
is there something wrong with my code?
thanks

[image: CATEGORY]
[image: PRODUCTS]
[image: MySqlException was unhandled]

Public Interface ISearchable
Property Id() As Integer
Property Name() As String
End Interface

```
An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in ServiceStack.OrmLite.dll

Additional information: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`inventory_manager`.`products`, CONSTRAINT `FK_products_categories_CategoryId` FOREIGN KEY (`CategoryId`) REFERENCES `categories` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
'update code for table  products
    <[Alias]("products")>
    Public Class Product
        Implements ISearchable

        <PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement>
        Public Property Id() As Integer Implements ISearchable.Id
        <ForeignKey(GetType(Category), OnDelete := "CASCADE")>
        Public Property CategoryId() As Integer
        Public Function GetCategory() As Category
            Return Db.Get().SingleById(Of Category)(Me.CategoryId)
        End Function

    End Class
```

```
'update code for table categories
<[Alias]("categories")>
Public Class Category
        Implements ISearchable

        <PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement>
        Public Property Id() As Integer Implements ISearchable.Id
        Public Property Name As String = String.Empty Implements ISearchable.Name
    End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the first table is `category` table with `id` as Primary key and the second table is `products` with `categoryid` as foreign key. While adding/editing records in `products` table, make sure the `categoryid` value is present in the parent table's `id` column. This is what the error means.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have updated my code in the post and the "CategoryId" is already in the products table